# Cannot access random part of youtube video in firefox

Tags: video, fedora, youtube

My computer is running on fedora 19 with gnash install (installing adobe flash is not an option for me since it's proprietary.), as well as Firefox.

Actually I can watch many YouTube videos using HTML5.

My problem is that I have to watch the video from beginning to end without the possibility of going backwards. If I try to go a few seconds backward the video freezes with the usual YouTube hourglass. I can pause the video without any problems though.

Then no video is able to work. I have to restart Firefox by deleting the lock and .parentlock files. Only then can I get video functionality.

Do you have any solution to this problem?